# url rewriting issues on magento installed at my local machine

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

hi i`m very new to magento.i'm working on already developed eCommerce site which is developed by magento.i installed in my local machine.there is some url rewritings issues in it.here is my live instance http://test.cstoremaster.com/.
every thing is working fine at my live instance but at my local machine it's not working fine,every time i need to put index.php at my url.even some pages were redirecting to my www folder it's like localhost/aboutus...help me

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this solution would work but you can try.

1. Login to you admin panel.
2. Go to System->Configuration.and click on **Web** tab.
3. Under **Search engine optimization** set the **web server rewrite**
   to **"Yes"**.
4. Save the changes.
   Now clear the cache if any enabled and check on frontend the problem of adding index.php should be fixed.

Hope this will help.

Regards,

Aton